# Problem Solving Steady State Navier Stokes Equations Using Finite Element Method

Tags: finite-element-method

I am using MMA 12.0.0 on a Mac running OS version 10.13.6.

Before attempting my own problem I am attempting to follow exactly the code in the FEM Documentation Tutorial, as an exercise:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html#1405680271

My version (after its first two lines) is supposed to be identical to that in the above tutorial as follows:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
NotebookSave[];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
rules = {length -> 22/10, hight -> 41/100};
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {length, hight}], 
    Disk[{1/5, 1/5}, 1/20]] /. rules;
region = RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
op = {\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, 
        y}\)] . \(({{\(-\[Mu]\), 0}, {0, \(-\[Mu]\)}} . 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)]u[x, y])\)\) + \[Rho] {{u[x, y],
          v[x, y]}}.\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)]\(u[x, y]\)\) + 
     Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y], \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, 
        y}\)] . \(({{\(-\[Mu]\), 0}, {0, \(-\[Mu]\)}} . 
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)]v[x, y])\)\) + \[Rho] {{u[x, y],
          v[x, y]}}.\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y}\)]\(v[x, y]\)\) + 
     Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y], 
    Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y] + 
     Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y]} /. {\[Mu] -> 10^-3, \[Rho] -> 1};
pde = op == {0, 0, 0};
bcs = {DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 4*0.3*y (hight - y)/hight^2, 
     x == 0], DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, x == 0], 
    DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0., v[x, y] == 0.}, 
     x > 0 && x < length], 
    DirichletCondition[p[x, y] == 0., x == length]} /. rules;
refinementRegion = 
  ImplicitRegion[
    a^4 (23 (y - 1/5))^2 + 
      b^2 (5/2 x - 2.05)^3 (2 a + (5/2 x - 2.05)) < 
     0, {{x, 0, length}, {y, 0, hight}}] /. 
   Flatten[{rules, a -> 1, b -> 5/2}];
Show[RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega]], RegionPlot[refinementRegion], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
mrf = With[{rmf = RegionMember[refinementRegion]}, 
   Function[{vertices, area}, Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Mean[vertices];
     If[rmf[{x, y}], area > 0.00025, area > 0.0025]]]];
{xVel, yVel, pressure} = 
  NDSolveValue[{pde, bcs}, {u, v, p}, 
   Element[{x, y}, \[CapitalOmega]], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, p -> 1}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"IncludePoints" -> {{0.15, 0.2}, {0.25, 0.2}}, 
       AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
       MeshRefinementFunction -> mrf}}];
```

After printing out the regions correctly, it returns the following warning/error messages:

NDSolveValue: The maximum derivative order of the nonlinear PDE coefficients for the Finite Element Method is larger than 1. It may help to rewrite the PDE in inactive form.

followed by a message that the two sides of my last command are not the same shape.

Perhaps I transcribed something wrong from the tutorial, but I can't see where. Otherwise, why does the tutorial not work in my version? I thought FEM was supposed to work in MMA 12?

Thanks.

Comment: When you evaluate the code in the tutorial does that work?

Comment: @user21. Actually yes! So, a transcription error. Sorry, I should have just cut and pasted from the start. When I cut-and-paste, many of the differential operators turn up as Inactive in my notebook. But those commands are "invisible" in the tutorial (perhaps that could be fixed in the tutorial, to prevent some other user having the same issue as I had)? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, what do you mean by 'fixed' : Do you mean that the equations should be typeset Inactive[Div][...] instead of what we have now? I mean I understand your point but how would I make that explicit in all the places where there are Inactive PDEs. Writing Inactive[...] everywhere will not be approved. A bit like what follows in FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM#156906496. Also note this section: FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM#205761584.

Comment: Thanks for helping! For some reason, we are not fully understanding each other. What I meant by "fixed" was to make it explicit somewhere in the tutorial that you have to set the Div operators Inactive. The cut-and-paste from the tutorial in my .nb, show-up as: "Inactive[Div]", which is, I guess, what you typed in your notebook. Why is the command "Inactive" suppressed in the code block in the tutorial? The typical user will not know that they are actually set Inactive. If you need to save space, you could just write below the code that all the Del operators need to be set Inactive.

Comment: OK, let's try to improve this. If you paste `{Inactive[
    Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
     u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Derivative[1, 0][p][x, y], 
 Inactive[Div][{{-\[Mu], 0}, {0, -\[Mu]}}.Inactive[Grad][
     v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + Derivative[0, 1][p][x, y], 
 Derivative[0, 1][v][x, y] + Derivative[1, 0][u][x, y]}` into your notebook if will format as a proper equation. You can use that formatted equation as input to `NDSolve`. Are you saying that it is better in the notebook to use the Inactive InputForm that the formatted equation.

Comment: I find the Inactive input form much harder to read, especially for coupled equations. While I may get away with Inactive in the FEM tutorials, Stephen will not approve this for the NDSolve reference pages. (I got to go now, but I will read you future comments later). I am sure we will figure out a way to improve this.

Comment: When I paste your code fragment above into my notebook, the [Mu] is rendered (in my input field) as a Greek letter, while the words "Derivative" and "Inactive" are rendered unchanged in words. Of course, in the output field, they are converted into a regular mathematical notation. Anyway, my concern is with the clarity of the tutorial itself for learners. Perhaps we are still talking at cross-purposes. Is it perhaps the case that the grey colouration (in the tutorial) is indicating that the operators have been set Inactive? If so, that is the answer (ie. I didn't realise that before now).

Comment: So, perhaps the thing which would be helpful and keep everyone happiest might be to add, just below the example code, something like: "The grey shading of the Del operators indicates that they have been set Inactive, see the Tips on using FEM" and a hyperlink, of course.

Comment: OK, I added links to a section that points put that Inactive PDEs are typeset with the operators in gray to indicate that these components are inactive. I have added this link after the first uses of Inactive typeset PDEs in the Solving PDE with FEM tutorial. I hope that this helps to avoid this problem in the future. Sorry again for your wait of time. I hope the fix is improves this now. If you have other suggestions let me know.

Comment: Allow me one more question: What was the reason you choose to not copy and paste the code from the tutorial?

Comment: @user21. Thanks for the update to the tutorial and for all the other help. Why did I not cut and paste? Well, I felt that was the lazy way and I would not learn much by doing it. I would learn more if I copied all the commands by hand and carefully thought about them as I went along. An object lesson in unintended consequences!